# How to analyse the performance of ANN for classification in Matlab? The performance graph is attached

Tags: performance, matlab, neural-network, face-recognition

I am using ORL face Database for face recognition. There are 40 subjects each with 10 images each. The size of each image is 112 * 92 pixels. For feature extraction and dimensionality reduction, I used 2D- PCA. The feature matrix is now 112*8.

Following is the Matlab code after feature extraction --

```
 % TrainFaces --- shape is 240 * 112 *8 (contains 240 images (8 images of 40 persons))
 % ValFaces --- shape is 80 * 112 *8 (contains 80 images (2 images of 40 persons))
 % TestFaces --- shape is 80 * 112 *8 (contains 80 images (2 images of 40 persons))
 % train_target -- shape is 40 * 240 (1st bit is 1 if it is 1st image and all rest zero)
 % val_target -- shape is 40 * 240
 % test_target -- shape is 40 * 240

 EigenFaces = [TrainFaces ; ValFaces ; TestFaces];
 target = [train_target val_target test_target];

 %%%%%%%%%% Now we can convert feature matrix into feature vector  %%%%%%%%%%%%%

 input = [];
    for i = 1:size(EigenFaces,1)
        input = [input reshape(EigenFaces(i,:,:),size(EigenFaces,2)*size(EigenFaces,3),1)]; 
    end

 %%%%%%%% Creating Network and Training Them %%%%%%%%%%%

 setdemorandstream(491218382);
 net = patternnet(25);
 net.divideFcn = 'divideind';
 [net.divideParam.trainInd, net.divideParam.valInd, net.divideParam.testInd] = divideind(400,1:240,241:320,321:400);     
 net.trainFcn = 'trainrp';
 [net,tr] = train(net,input,target);

 %%%%%%%%%%%%% Testing the network %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 predict = 0;  % Number of correctly identified images out of 80
     for i =1:80
         [tar_val tar_ind] = max(test_target);
         [out_val out_ind] = max(net(reshape(TestFaces(i,:,:),size(TestFaces,2)*size(TestFaces,3),1)));
         if tar_ind == out_ind
             predict = predict +1;
         end
     end
     predict
```

The predict always shows zero.

Following is the snapshot of the result. Kindly help me analysis from the graph. Any help would be really grateful.

The predict always shows zero.

Following is the snapshot of the result. Kindly help me analysis from the graph. Any help would be really grateful.

[Snapshot of NNtrainTool](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8B53D84E27F1598C!4245&authkey=!AIfENUntYnPZWB0&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

[Snapshot of Performance](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8B53D84E27F1598C!4244&authkey=!ALqRwkv6Q08MPqw&v=3&ithint=photo%2CPNG)

Comment: by reading manuals first http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/analyze-neural-network-performance-after-training.html

Comment: @madbitloman : Thank you for the suggestion. But I have read the manual. The performance parameters come into rescue which dealing with regression or function approximation problem. Is there any parameter which I can rely to for stopping the training in classification problem? Or I have to write explicitly the testing case for a batch of epoch and stop when classification rate is 90 % (let say) ?

Comment: you can test the performance of your network by testing it on separate set of samples that have not been provided to the network(also known as leave-one-out)